# Cruise Control .Net - Builds across domains

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, dns

Currently our developent enviroment consists of a Dev server, a Staging server and a Production server.  Our production server and staging server live on the same domain while our build server and dev server are on a different domain.

Is it possible to have my build server (Cruisecontrol .Net) access the two servers that are outside its domain?  If so, can my build user in one domain have access to another domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cruise Control.Net will do anything you want it to but you will have to do some of the plumbing. All Cruise Control.Net is a tool that helps you with continuous-integration it is not seamless and it does require some work to set up.

If you are trying to "Push" the build to multiple locations it is possible, but you will have to set it up(as far as I am aware). We use a FTP transfer in conjunction with [Robocopy](http://Robocopy) to push the builds to multiple areas on different domains and then copy the files over our current ones.

This is a great [article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/06/asp-net-website-continuous-integration-deployment-using-cruisecontrol-net-subversion-msbuild-and-robocopy.aspx) on getting started with Cruise control if you are interested.

Good luck